# linear algebra - raising a matrix to a certain degree

Tags: linear-algebra

If you are given any matrix A with certain entries and are asked to compute the same matrix raised to any power such as k, are you supposed to raise each entry in the matrix to the k-th degree?

Comment: Nope.  $$A^2 = AA, \quad A^3=AAA,\quad \dots\quad ,\quad A^k = \underbrace{A\cdots A}_{k \text{ times}}$$

Answer (score 2):

No, you are supposed to multiply $A$ by itself $k$ times using [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) (in most contexts).

So, for example, if
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}
$$
Then $A^2$ will be 
$$
A^2 = AA = \pmatrix{1&2\\0&1}
$$
and will not be the same as $A$.